# tar made a directory from a DB-file on Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, tar

I have a database file repository.db, I've made the following by mistake:

```
$ tar cvf repository.db repository.db.part1.tar
tar: repository.db.part1.tar: No such file or directory
```

instead of

```
tar cvf repository.db.part1.tar repository.db
```

now my repository.db looks like a directory
-rwxr-xr-x+  1 gw       greenwich    1024 Aug 13 17:55 /pool/greenwich/dictionary/repository_ipdr_test/part1/repository.db

is it possible to recover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to following simple experiment, the file was filled with NULL characters. No previous content was found; Recovery is impossible for me.

*I don't have solaris box. I experimentd in Ubuntu Linux 13.04 (GNU tar 1.26); Result may be different on Solaris*

```
$ echo hello > 1
$ cat 1
hello
$ tar cvf 1 no-such-file
tar: no-such-file: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
$ ls -l 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 falsetru falsetru 10240 Aug 13 23:29 1
$ cat 1
$ od -x 1
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
0024000
```

Comment: @fen1ksss, Above experiment show that tar overwrite source file with null characters (at least in my system).

Answer (score 1):

Your file has been overwritten and the original content is lost.

You could argue that `tar c` command should ask before overwriting an existing archive of the same name but that's just not the way it works. (neither GNU tar or Sun tar works that way).

Your question is effectively about how to recover a previous version of a file. This will depend on what backup produces are in place at your site. Furthermore if you are using ZFS you may be in luck that there's a recent snapshot from which you can copy a previous version of that file.